# Permission denied in Android terminal Emulator

Tags: android

i always get **permission denied**  when i open the android terminal emulator?
I want to change the hosts for android , but I cant because the permission denied ?
How can I fix it ?

**I want to change the host to point on another pc so i see the request there and check if there the service is from a mobile device so i can reroute it to mobile page**

Comment: Please give some more details. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you have the permission :

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: I want to change the host in my android emulator using adb , but its give me permission denied , even i cant do ll or any command in the terminal

Comment: Does the permission denied come when you want to start 'adb shell' - than kill the adb and restart it as Admin.

Comment: I tried to `su` but its showing that uid is not allowed to su

Answer (score 0):

The android on board "toolbox" shell has a limited vocabulary of errors, and likes to go give the permission denied one for all sorts of causes, such as command not found.

It also has a rather limited assortment of commands, some of which do not take formats familiar from the desktop linux world.

Comment: can you explain more please  How can i fix that?

Comment: I edited the answer, for those who asked for explanation, and i added comments, thanks for participating

Comment: ok, Thank you, hope next time my question will be more effective

Comment: If you are actually using a terminal emulator app to get a shell, don't.  Almost nothing in the way of configuration can be done from from the userid of an app.  You can do a little bit temporarily form the adb shell on a secured device, substantially more from the adb shell on an unsecured device.